# How to include raw html file?

Tags: asciidoctor

In rst, I can easily include a raw html file using the `raw` directive as follows:

```rst
.. raw:: html
    :file: some_file.html
```

Is there a simple way to do this with asciidoctor? I understand that if I wrap the contents of `some_file.html` with `++++` that I can then use `include::` in asciidoc, but I would like to avoid manually editing `some_file.html`.

Answer (score 9):

Asciidoctor allows you to put includes into a passthrough block, ideally surrounded by empty lines, like this:

```
++++
include::some_file.html[]
++++
```

Adding empty lines around this prevents interpretation of the included file contents as continuations of the adoc text surrounding the include, as described in the [manual](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-directive).